# How can I gracefully handle a Kafka outage?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am connecting to Kafka using the 0.8.2.1 kafka-clients library. I am able to successfully connect when Kafka is up, but I want to handle failure gracefully when Kafka is down. Here is my configuration:

```
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaUrl);
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, "3");
producer = new KafkaProducer(kafkaProperties);
```

When Kafka is down, I get the following error in my logs:

```
WARN: 07 Apr 2015 14:09:49.230 org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector:276 - [] Error in I/O with localhost/127.0.0.1
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:739) ~[na:1.7.0_75]
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238) ~[kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:122) [kafka-clients-0.8.2.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_75]
```

This error repeats in an infinite loop and locks up my Java application. I have tried various configuration settings related to timeouts, retries, and acknowledgements, but I have been unable to prevent this loop from occurring.

Is there a configuration setting that can prevent this? Do I need to try a different version of the client? How can a Kafka outage be handled gracefully?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I figured out that this combination of settings allows the kafka client to fail quickly without holding the thread or spamming the logs:

```
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.METADATA_FETCH_TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "300");
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.TIMEOUT_CONFIG, "300");
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
kafkaProperties.setProperty(ProducerConfig.RECONNECT_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG, "10000");
```

I dislike that the kafka client holds the thread while trying to connect to the kafka server, rather than being fully async, but this at least is functional.

Comment: Very helpful, thank you. Is this officially documented anywhere?

Comment: @maxenglander: Not that I saw. I had to go poking through code and there was lots of trial and error.

Comment: "rather than being fully async"

Answer (score 0):

In the 0.9 client, there's also the `max.block.ms` property, which will limit the time the client is allowed to run.